# Probability of a weather event occurring at the same time using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

My question says,

**On Wednesday the weather forecast for Thursday was 60% chance of rain and a 35% chance of rain on Friday.  If there is a 20% chance of rain on both Thursday and Friday, what is the probability that there will be rain on Thursday or Friday?**

I have to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to determine the probability of events occuring at the same time, but I'm not sure how to. Please help! Any and all suggestions and help is appreciated!

Comment: So what is the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion that you have learnt?

Comment: $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$.  The probability of rain on thursday or friday is equal to the probability of rain on thursday plus the probability of rain on friday minus the probability of rain on both days.

Comment: @JMoravitz would that be the answer?

Comment: Once you plug in the numbers... yes... Did you have any doubt about it?